# dynamic parameters for views in hive without recreating the view each time

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql, bigdata

I want to create a view which has dynamic parameters set.For example

```
set x=2;

create view y as select * from k where id=${hiveconf:x}
```

now am setting `x=4;`

The view gets repopulated with `x=4` values

So, I want the views to be created once and populated with different values based on x

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, consider using [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title and other [necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [head on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create view only once, you can use **'IF NOT EXISTS'** and an  '**ALTER**' statement to populate the view from the next time for your new X values

```
set x=2;
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS Y as select * from k where id=${hiveconf:x};
ALTER VIEW Y as select * from k where id=${hiveconf:x};
```

I guess, the only small drawback  with this approach is that for the very first time same operation is done twice (create and alter) , from the next values of x , it should be fine.